# H5BP Build Script Image Optimization

Tags: html5boilerplate, build-script

When i run the build script everything works fine but because of the amount of images it takes about 5 minutes to build. Isn't the build script supposed to check if the images are modified since the last build and let them be if they aren't? If it isn't, is there an easy way to exclude folders from the build?

The only warning i get is a "modified in the future"-warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple workaround is doing `ant text` instead of `ant build` or `ant minify` or whatever. Still irritating though.